# Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

Hi guys i have a controller code with the following :

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.create(feedback_params)

    if @feedback.errors.any?
      flash[:error] = @feedback.errors
      render 'new'
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end

  end
```

**test spec**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe FeedbacksController do

  describe "POST create" do           

    context 'when param[:name] is present' do
        it 'should redirect to homepage' do
          @feedback = Feedback.create(:name => "Hah")
          @feedback.save
          is_expected.to redirect_to new_feedback_path
          debugger
        end
      end
  end
end
```

However when i run localhost, the output is exactly what i want but as of the unit test, it's not passing but returning me 
"Expected response to be a m was was <200> ."

May i know why is it so and how should i pass my test case ?

Comment: What's your subject? `describe "PUT create"` - PUT is for update.

Comment: I don't understand how you are even getting a 200 response. I don't see any call to your controller at all in your test.

Comment: @AlexKojin I've re-edit them. Haha thx for telling me that.

Comment: @David wouldn't the Feedback.create call the controller ?

Comment: no ... thats creating an instance of the Feedback model.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the actual post request to your controller.

Please read this: [rspec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec)

So this:

```
      @feedback = Feedback.create(:name => "Hah")
      @feedback.save
```

Should not be there. The second line is superfluous anyway, create already saves the object.

You are looking for code like this:

```
   it 'should redirect to homepage' do
      post feedback_path, params: { name: 'hah' }
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_feedback_path)
    end
```